# Can you play Shadows of Mordor in first person (à la Skyrim)?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I have been looking (and drooling) at Shadows of Mordor for some time now, and the only stopping me from buying it on PC is the third person view. I don't own a console, and spending that much money only to play SoM seems a bit much. Therefore I was wondering if anyone can confirm that you can absolutely *not* play this game in first person.

I had hoped SoM was a Lord of the Rings spin-off of Skyrim. But it seems to be more of the play style of Batman and AC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no first-person mode.

In the future, someone could make a mod, that would allow first person, but as of yet, there is no such thing.

I personally doubt that there ever will be, because the fights are fast an frantic (like in the Batman Arkham games), with many spins, jumps, back attacks etc., so a first person mode would make fighting awkward.

Comment: Yeah, fighting in first person in this game would not work at all.